# File locked after uploaded by using HttpServletRequest in JAVA

Tags: java, servlets, file-upload

Here is the scenario, I try to upload a file, and after I uploaded it, I tried to access that file from the new directory (which i just write to), but I received error message:

> There was an error opening this document. The file is already open or
>   in use by another application.

Below is my coding.

```
try{
    conn = this.getConnection();
    String getIP = "SELECT IP FROM TABLE WHERE ID='3'";
    ps = conn.prepareStatement(getIP);
    rs = ps.executeQuery();

    Part file = request.getPart("upload");
    String fileName = extractFileName(request.getPart("upload"));
    String basePath = "//"+ipAdd+"/ns/"+fileName;
    File outputFilePath = new File(basePath + fileName);

    inputStream = file.getInputStream();
    outputStream = new FileOutputStream(outputFilePath);

    int read = 0;
    final byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
    while ((read = inputStream.read(bytes)) != -1) {
        outputStream.write(bytes, 0, read);
    }
}catch(Exception ex){
    ex.printStackTrace(); 
    throw ex;
}finally{
    if(!conn.isClosed())conn.close();
    if(!ps.isClosed())ps.close();
    if(!rs.isClosed())rs.close();
    inputStream.close();
    outputStream.close();
}
```

Is it because that I open the file too quick after I start the upload function? I do realize that after 1/2minutes, I'm able to access the file. Is there anyway to solve this bug?

Comment: Did you forget to close your streams?

Comment: I didn't, they are closed in the 'finally' after the 'try'

Comment: I see no `finally` or `try` in the code above. Please include all relevant code. One way or another, it seems your OutputStream is not being closed.

Comment: Added in... the problem still exists

Comment: I notice your OutputStream is the last thing you try and close, and that's the significant one. I leave you to think about what might happen if another exception is thrown whilst executing the finally block, before reaching that last close().

Comment: So I should close it right after the while loop and inside the catch as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code above, if an exception occurs whilst closing the JDBC Connection, then none of the other JDBC objects or Streams are closed. The finally block exits at that point.

Since Java 7, closing Streams and JDBC objects (Connections, Statements, ResultSets etc) can be done in a proper exception handling framework nice and easily, since they all implement a common interface `AutoCloseable`

So you can write a single `close()` method and handle the exception inside:

```
public void close(AutoCloseable closeable) {
  try {
    closeable.close();
  } catch (Exception e) {
    //Just log the exception. there's not much else you can do, and it probably doesn't
    //matter. Don't re-throw! 
  }
}
```

So when closing your JDBC objects, you can do this in the finally block:

```
close(conn);
close(ps);
close(rs);
close(inputStream);
close(outputStream);
```

Now if an exception occurs whilst closing any of the objects, it is handled and the following objects are still closed.

Comment: Try-with-resources remains a simpler and cleaner solution.

Comment: @EJP thanks for the tip - I will look into it. New to Java 7.

Answer (score 2):

You're not closing the file. Add

```
outputStream.close();
```

after the loop.

**EDIT** And do it first, before closing anything else. You should really use try-with-resources here. If you get any exception closing anything, the other closes won't happen.

Comment: I didn't put in the try catch, but i do closed both my inputStream and outputStream.

Comment: Not in the code you posted. If the file is really closed you wouldn't have this problem. Ergo you aren't closing it. If you think otherwise, show the code for comment.

Comment: The file is accessible after 1 minute, would it be the uploading process going on? So i'm not able to access the file?

Comment: Until you deign to post your secret code it is impossible to comment further.

Comment: Added in, the problem still exists.